# TreeView - detect node position change

Tags: c#, treeview

I have TreeView:

```
Group01
 - PackageP1
    - ComponentC1
    - ComponentC2
Group02
 - PackageP2
    - ComponentC3
    - ComponentC4
Group03
 - PackageP3
    - ComponentC5
    - ComponentC6
```

The position of the nodes of this treeview can be changed via Drag&Drop, keyboard hotkey and separate Up/Down buttons. How to react when node will change it's position on the TreeView? I didn't find anything which might be Event OnNodeIndexChange.

Comment: maybe you can use ItemDrag Event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.itemdrag?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I can't use ItemDrag Event because node can be moved also via keyboard hotkey and separate button.

Comment: I can't find an event either. But: All these occasions are in __your code, so you can call__ a method from each one..

Comment: @TaW Yep that was easiest solution, thanks!